# Сервер на Java, способ реализации

Tags: java, сервер, клиент-сервер, спецификация

Доброго утра. Хочу сделать приложение: сервер на Java + клиенты (Десктоп на C#, андроид, ios, браузер), сомневаюсь какую из реализаций (или как это назвать) для сервера выбрать, REST, SOAP, Сокеты, мб еще что-то есть? Склонялся к SOAP, но очень смущает куча XML + люди говорят что он потихоньку погибает. Хочется услышать мысли людей еоторые сталкивались с подобными задачами.

Или может быть подскажете направление, где посмотреть, что почитать, какие вообще серверы бывают, кроме этих, под подобные задачи.

Comment: REST и SOAP - архитектурные подходы,  на первый взгляд SOAP сложнее, но это только на первый взгляд. Сокеты - много писать и крайне неудобно поддерживать.  Лучше всего начните писать REST сервис, по мере обростания функционалом будете решать что Вам необходимо.